# Ubuntu Touch - Screen locking fade issue

Tags: ubuntu-touch, security, lock-screen

On my Ubuntu phone, I have set my screen lock to come on after a minute of none use. This is in the Settings > Security & Privacy > Locking & Unlocking. The lock does come on as requested however, it is instant. One second the screen is on and then the next the screen is locked and black. There is no fade (like on my Ubuntu tablet), which fades out giving me the option to cancel the locking, if you wish to.

Is there a setting that stops my phone from locking so fast and where I can increase the fade?

Comment: This is such a pain on the phone. Today, I was trying to connect some Bluetooth devises to my phone. Whilst performing a scan, the phone suddenly locked and went black after a minute. If it was to fade out slowly like the tablet, that would of been much better, as I would of had time to swipe the phone display. As it was it was one second the Bluetooth screen and then the next it was locked and black. Is there no settings I can change and not the time out period.

Comment: I have logged this under the following defect - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1577128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I installed the new update and the fade issue when the timeout is set to 1 minute has been resolved. Now when set to one minute, the screen fades out and then locks. Giving you time to deactivate the fade/lock if you want to.

Great work guys, thanks for including this in the latest release.